# How to handle negative JUNIT test case for Elasticsearchn CRUD operation

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, junit5

I have created a JUNIT test cases for elasticsearch CRUD operation i have given the code below. After code reviewing phase i got an update from team that i have covered all the positive scenario of test cases still not yet covered the negative scenarios. I am not aware of handling the negative use cases.

```
@Test
void findById() throws Exception {

    EmployeeInformation EmployeeGet = Eservice.findById("elcrud", "2");

    assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getId());

    assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getFirstName());

    assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getLastName());

}

@Test
void deleteProfileDocument() throws Exception {

    String Result = Eservice.deleteProfileDocument("elcrud", "3");

    System.out.println(Result);

    assertEquals(Result, "DELETED");
}

@Test
void search() throws Exception {

    List<EmployeeInformation> Emp=Eservice.searchByTechnology("Lucidworks","elcrud");

    System.out.println(Emp.size());

    int Result = Emp.size();

    assertTrue(Result  >= 0 );
}

@Test
void searchByName() throws Exception {

    List<EmployeeInformation> Emp=Eservice.findProfileByName("junit","elcrud");

    System.out.println(Emp.size());

    int Result = Emp.size();

    assertTrue(Result  >= 0 );
}
```

Could some one help me to implement the negative scenario of JUNIT test cases for above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you tech team wants a test if the operation of ES failed, give no results or any other unexpected scenario happens.

One example could be the deletion of a profile document:

You already covered the test if the delete operation is successful. But you dont have a test if this operation failed or is not handled successful.

```
@Test
void deleteProfileDocument() throws Exception {

    //here you delete a profile which is NOT in the index
    String Result = Eservice.deleteProfileDocument("elcrud", "3");

    System.out.println(Result);

    //and here you asssert the negative result. (Not sure which result will come)
    assertEquals(Result, "NOT_FOUND");
}
```

I also see that on your test you throw an exception in case of an error. This could be another good negative test scenario. So, if you can send an operation to ES and this operation throws an exception you can create a test to expect this exception.

For Junit4 you could use the following:

```
@Test(expected = YourExpectedException.class)
```

For Junit5 you could use this:

```
Exception exception = assertThrows(YourExpectedException.class, () -> {
        Eservice.findProfileByName(Exception values);
    });

    String expectedMessage = "expected message";
    String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();

    assertTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));
```

---

**EDit by addtional questions**

If you have a positive and a negeative test, I would suggest to keep them in separate test methods. So there will be no need to comment things out and in.

In your case it could be like:

positve:

```
@Test
void testUpdateItem_POSITIVE() throws Exception {
....
}
```

negative:

```
@Test
void testUpdateItem_NEGATIVE() throws Exception {
....
}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, As suggested by you i have created code samples and given below. Kindly review my code and answer my queries?

Comment: In case of any clarification, Post ur comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Test(expected = NotFound.class)
void shouldThrowExceptionWhenProfileIsNotExist() throws Exception {

    Eservice.findById("elcrud", "some_id");
}
```

Instead NotFound place your exception which is thrown when search profile with an id which is not exist